# docker -v: не могу понять, как это делать под виндой!

Tags: windows, postgresql, docker, windows-10

я пытаюсь адаптировать команду

```
    docker run -d --name postgres -v $(pwd)/DB:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres -N 102
```

для запуска под виндой. Создаю директорию `C:\DData\DB` и пытаюсь именно туда положить базы:

```
    docker run -d --name postgres -v C:\DData\DB:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust postgres -N 102
```

При запуске этой команды контейнер стартует, никаких ошибок не выдаётся, но никакие базы в указанной директории не появляются.

Не могли бы Вы указать мне, где я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Почему используете путь `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d`? postgres по-умолчанию хранит данные в `/var/lib/postgresql/data`, значить и volume нужно мапить по тому пути. `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` это путь откуда при первом запуске контейнера запускаются скрипты, т.е. можно использовать для инициализации, если присоединить туда папку с *.sql и *.sh файлами. Сам контейнер там ничего не создаст.

Comment: @RomanKonoval -  спасибо, я этого не знал - посмотрел, а там действительно папка со скриптами для инициализации базы.