# К вопросу https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1376042/

Tags: docker

Возник такой же вопрос с указанием пути к папке с готовой базой данных в команде для докера. В папке `C:\database\demo` лежит файл `initdb.sql`. Есть команда

```sh
docker run --name Demo_postgres_db -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty -v "/c/database/demo":/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -d postgres:13.9
```

В докере создается контейнер, в IDEA видно подключение к постгрессу, однако саму базу в IDEA найти не могу.

Как правильно указать путь к папке с базой? И что нужно указать в этом пути?

Comment: очевидно, что путь к каталогу с (пока не созданной) базой данных вам на самом деле не нужен. вероятно, вам надо создать базу данных, и, судя по имени файла, именно из него — `initdb.sql`. процесс внутри контейнера видит этот файл как `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initdb.sql`. вот и передавайте его интерпретатору.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin Извините, но я не понял ваш ответ. Что же всё таки нужно указать в пути к директории с существующей базой и как правильно это сделать?

Comment: 1. вам не нужен путь к базе данных. базой данных занимается сервер баз данных. это его «хозяйство». вам там нечего делать. 2. более того, ни о каком пути к файлам базы данных не может быть и речи, так как база данных у вас не создана. о чём сами и пишете. вот на этом и сосредоточьтесь.

Comment: судя по всей изложенной вами информации, представление о базах данных у вас довольно поверхностное. давайте начнём с начала. вот вы пишете: `однако саму базу в IDEA найти не могу` — каким образом вы «ищете базу данных в idea»? (кстати, что это за клиент такой? мне кажется, так называется какая-то ide или что-то в этом роде. вы уверены, что эта ваша «idea» умеет общаться с сервером баз данных postgresql?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Отредактировал команду для докера, изменив написание пути к папке с sql файлом:
   docker run --name Demo_postgres_db -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty -v с:\database\demo:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d -d postgres:13.9
2. После создания контейнера в Docker Desktop щелкнул по названию контейнера мышью. База данных, лежащая на диске, подтянулась к дефолтной.
3. В idea создал подключение с логином и паролем. Вместе с дефолтной базой подгрузился и sql файл demo[image: введите сюда описание изображения]